# Selecting only some relations

Tags: mysql, select

I have 3 tables: A, B, C.
Tables A and C have fields: `ID`, `Name` and they are related many-to-many through B table with fields `A_ID`, `C_ID`.

How can I select the entries from A which have relations **only** to the entries from C called 'Mike' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B on B.A_ID = A.ID
INNER JOIN C on C.ID = B.C_ID
WHERE C.Name = 'Mike'
```

Comment: please, in addition to the solution, add a brief explanation.